# Delete register of a model in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

My question is: I have a model. I want to delete a register in the model that depends of other model in a "has_many" relation. If I want to delete a register in a model. the other model will have at least a register without link and if I try to do a query, Rails will do error. How I can resolve this??  This is the model:

```
class Vehiculo < ActiveRecord::Base
mount_uploader :imagen
belongs_to :empresa
belongs_to :marca
has_many :fotos
validates :empresa, :marca, :matricula,:matriculacion,:plazas, :presence => true
def to_s
    "#{matricula}" 
end
end
```

If delete a vehiculo, when I go to the fotos model, I get an error. For example, in Fotos index I get this:

```
undefined method `matricula' for 5:Fixnum
```

Comment: can you provide an example as well as the model code...

Comment: yes, this is the code:

Comment: I think this is the solution: I have to put thsi code in the model : dependent: :destroy in the has_many relation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like:

```
has_many :fotos, dependent: :destroy
```

So when you delete Vehiculo, it will delete fotos related to that Vehiculo.

Comment: You can accept my answer as you have created this question